# How to get element value from response data to json

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, restsharp, web-api-testing

Im writing an API automation test with RestSharp.Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated!
I'm getting data values from the response & I need to write few values to my json file (which I will use for another test putting them as a body).
I managed to get 1 value from JArray but I need 2 more values and I cant wrap my head around how to do that.
Im attaching my api test code & the data I get from the response + the data I managed to write into my json file.

The value that I managed to get: FsNumber (declared it as financialNumber). What I need to add to the json: subjectName + subjectCode (they will be declared as companyName/companyCode). How do I access "Query" list with SubjectName/SubjectCode?

TEST

```cs
var queryResult = client.Execute<object>(request);

var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryResult.Data);

var jsonParse = JToken.Parse(data);

var fsObject = jsonParse.Value<JToken>("FinanceReportList");
var fsArray = fsObject.Value<JArray>("List");

foreach (var fs in fsArray)
{
    var cfn = fs.Value<string>("FsNumber");

    var queryObject = new DataQuery
    {
        financialNumber = cfn,
    };

    var queryObjectString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryObject);
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\TestAPI\myJsonWithValues.json", queryObjectString);
}
```

Data I get from the response:

```json
{
  "RequestDate": "2021-07-16",
  "Message": "Active",
  "ProductNumber": 666,
  "Language": "EN",
  "RequestId": "reqID666",
  "Query": {
    "SubjectCode": "MY-SUBJECT",
    "SubjectName": "MY-NAME"
  },
  "FinanceReportList": {
    "List": [
      {
        "FsNumber": "MY-NUMBER",
        "Year": 2021,
```

So far I managed to get FsNumber to my myJsonWithValues.json file as this:
`{"financialNumber":"MY-NUMBER","companyName":null,"companyCode":null}`
What Im trying to do is, my json should  look like
`{"financialNumber":"MY-NUMBER","companyName":MY-NAME,"companyCode":MY-CODE}`

Comment: did u try to read values from Query field? That's where your data is. var fsQuery = jsonParse.Value<JToken>("Query"); It's a good practice to encapsulate response like so https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0 to deserialize json into object

Comment: Yup tried it but now Im getting System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty. :( @michal.materowski

Comment: Did you try to use Children() method to access children of query object? var jsonData = JObject.Parse(json).Children();
List<JToken> tokens = jsonData .Children().ToList(); Maybe try debugging your test first to see what kind of object you're getting and what methods can you call on the result. That's always a good start.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. Totally forgot about debugging. @michal.materowski

Comment: Managed to set it up with var fsQuery = jsonParse.Value<JToken>("Query"); as Michal stated. Debugged the response, found a mistake, corrected it and it works like a charm.
Thank you again! @michal.materowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access "Query" object

```
  var fsQuery = jsonParse.Value<JToken>("Query")
```

and use Children() method to access properties of "Query"

```
var children = fsQuery.Children();
```

It is a good practice to implement a class that encapsulates your resonse and deserialize it with JsonConvert.Deserialize eg.

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);
```

Instead of using JObjects